# Create asset for GitLab release

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am able to successfully create a release with the GitLab API but I am trying to create an additional asset that has a link in the release, package.zip. The release currently has the entire code as a zip but I am wanting to create a zip out of a subset of the repo.

Reading here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html#permanent-links-to-release-assets

It looks like I needed to do something similar to the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/releases"
    headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': os.environ['CI_JOB_TOKEN']}
    data = {'tag_name': 'Lite-Release',
            'assets': {
                'links': [{
                    'name': 'link_test',
                    'url': 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/releases/Lite-Release/downloads',
                    'filepath': '/package.zip', 'link_type': 'other'}]
            }}
    post_resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(post_resp.text)
```

This returns the error: `{"error":"assets is invalid"}`
What am I missing here?
Is the `url` field supposed to be what I want the url to be or what?

Edit: It does not appear to be a JSON formatting issue as the following works fine and creates a release.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/releases"
    headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': os.environ['PRIVATE_TOKEN']}
    data = {'tag_name': 'tag_test', 'ref': 'HEAD'}
    post_resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(post_resp.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did the same as you using curl, compared the data json, and everything seems ok.

Had previously problems with the CI_JOB_TOKEN, which can create a release (as stated in the docs - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#gitlab-cicd-job-token), however it has not enough privileges to include assets - got a 401, instead of the error message you get. Might be a difference in the Gitlab server version..

By using a Personal Access Token I was able to make the creation of a release with package asset possible.

Answer (score -1):

When [creating a release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/index.html#create-a-release) via API the **data** is a JSON-object.

The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) requires double quotes and will not accept single quotes.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a formatting issue with the quotes. See the edit I have added. There is something specifically wrong with the assets section.

Comment: _Python_ knows that a `'string'` is a `"string"` though, and its Python's job to marshal the JSON correctly. This isn't the issue.

Comment: @AdamSmith you're right. In _python_ this is not a problem. It would fail with _curl_ .

Comment: @JakobLiskow absolutely true! Don't get me wrong I appreciate the lookout. I'm jumping between various languages, runtimes, and shells pretty consistently and the first thing I look for when something unexpectedly fail is "Did I quote it correctly?" (Or more commonly: did I escape my quotes correctly!)